# iPhone/iPad alarm clock app with custom radio stream support

Tags: iphone, ipad, applications, alarm

Is there a iPhone (or even better iPad) alarm clock app that will play a radio stream of my choosing to wake me up?

With custom stream I mean the possibility to enter a custom URL to a .pls file, and that pls contains a URL to a mp3.

Something like [TimeTurner](http://www.dreamsurface.com) but with the custom stream support.

Answer (score 3):

[TuneIn Radio](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/tunein-radio/id418987775?mt=8). I've not looked back since.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you tell us more about this app? What makes it special, and why do you like it? Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: It's good, but the iPhone app at least doesn't seem to have an alarm function.

Comment: 2018 and still no alarm function in TuneIn for iPhone :(

Answer (score 1):

[Radio Alarm](http://itunes.apple.com/app/radio-alarm-mp3-radio-nature/id380271167?mt=8) is a great iPhone app that works well with custom streams (.pls file that points to a MP3) and has a lot of well working alarm features.

Answer (score 0):

[Tunemark Radio](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tunemark-radio/id325681153?mt=8) is a iPad/iPhone app that support custom streams (.pls file that points to a MP3), but isn't really written to work as a alarm clock so has poor alarm features.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2016 (post iOS 8.0):

[Bedr radio alarm clock](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bedr-radio-alarm-clock/id1053241118?ls=1&mt=8), which is able to run in a background state.