# How to trigger iOS-Alarm to start another app in iOS Shortcuts-App?

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

I am really looking for a Radio-Clock for my iPhone. This seems to be non-trivial looking at [iPhone/iPad alarm clock app with custom radio stream support](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/iphone-ipad-alarm-clock-app-with-custom-radio-stream-support?r=SearchResults&s=1|64.4808) . All proposed solutions require the app to be running until the alarm goes off. Now that we have Shortcuts this should be a piece of cake: start Alarm -> when done -> play my favourite radio url. Or is it not? Is there a reason in case it is not (besides Apple did not implemented it)?

Comment: "All proposed solutions require the app to be running until the alarm goes off." i believe not only that but the app has to be in foreground to open
a url. It's all sandboxed. If you allow one app to start another without
explicit user interaction it brings issues with spam and malicious apps I suppose. It's a problem on desktop with sites opening safari windows.
Excerpt on desktop you have lots of leverage going around to squash the offender
(and it's not easy even there).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about iOS devices, but if you have a HomePod, you could use the Home.app.

Home.app > Bottom of screen > Automation > Create Automation

Select "A Time of Day Occurs" > Time Of Day > Next

Select your HomePod > Next

Select When > Then Turn Off > set timer

Select Media > Choose Audio

Radio

Select station.

This may help others.

Comment: When does the alarm stop and the radio start you seem to only have the radio start

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Basically you set the start time, and then for how long. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: The issue is what I want is sound the loud alarm, tell siri to stop when I wake up, then play the radio (or other things)/ I don't know beforehand how long the alarm needs to ring to wake me up.

Comment: You could program getting the radio played as the wake up, leave a large stop time -- maybe 45 minutes -- and "Hey Siri - Stop"

Comment: This automation also works for iOS in the shortcuts app. The only issue is that you have to have the phone unlocked in order to trigger the automation. So unless you unlock it immediately after you have turned off your alarm (not snooze), you will have a limited amount of time (less than a minute?) to unlock the phone to trigger it. Otherwise the automation will fail to run.

Comment: If people cast a down vote, shouldn't they announce themselves and explain why?

Comment: @ICL1901 There are lots of threads on meta stackexchange explaining why - however in this case read the comments